# How to "insulate" Singletons in JUnit?

Tags: junit, singleton

I'm using a 3rd party library for a server / client program. The server / client allow to register a specific data model (details are not important at all here).

In my unit tests, I have roughly the following:

```
private static MyServerType myServer;  // my class, derived from a 3rd party class
private static MyClientType myClient;  // my class, derived from 3rd party
private static int modelId = 123;      // identifier to identify the data model

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    int modelId
    myServer = new MyServerType();
    myServer.registerDataModel(modelId, new ServerDataModel());
    myClient = new MyClientType();
    myClient.registerDataModel(modelId, new ClientDataModel());

}
```

When I run this code, it fails - because internally (we can look at the source code), the library has a **Singleton** (static class with .getInstance() ) which registers the models by Id, and finds that there is already a model with this Id registered.

How can I run the unit tests where I want to test the client / server interaction? (Both the server and client are own programs derived from the 3rd party library classes, so I need to test both, and their interaction)

In the `@BeforeClass` method I could start an external (java) program which runs the freshly compiled server. This looks somehow quite ugly.

Is there a way to "insulate" the server or client within the unit test (like a "virtual machine" inside the JVM :) for either process), so that getInstance() returns different objects for server and client, grouped e.g. by thread / thread group or something similar?

ps: yes, this is an example why singletons are evil - but I have to live with it.

**EDIT:** I have split the business logic from the server logic so that I can test business logic independently. What I want to test is that the server works as proper front-end for the business logic, that is, updates all data changes and triggers function calls on the business logic on user requests.

Is this kind of test "too big" for a unit test (i.e. integration test)?

Especially: If I use only a trivial client, i.e. a stub client which just speaks the protocol, just to test that the server provides the correct data etc. - would such tests (e.g. `@Test public void test_publishes_updates_on_VARIABLEX() { ... }` `@Test public void test_calls_backend_functionY_and_returns_formatted_reply() { ... }` ) be unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before asking questions about how you would ideally expect this to work, my response would be:  don't unit test like that.  I would try to test my client code and server code in isolation of one another.  Presumably this framework has some mechanism you use to communicate from a client, to a server, and potentially vice versa.  Possibly you talk from one to another through some interface or superclass methods provided by the framework?  I would stub these out - if it is an interface this is easy, if they are superclass methods you have to do a little wrapper work - and then verify that for example my client - when I exercise a particular feature on that client class - attempts to communicate with the server in the correct way.  To give you tips on how to tease that apart if the communication between the two isn't already handled by an interface - I would need to see the library you are using.

Now, as to how you ideally want it to work - where you have the client and server interacting with one another inside the JVM.  I'm not sure that is possible, as your framework obviously expects these not to be in the same process - hence the uniqueness of the ID.  You would seemingly need to start both your client and server in separate processes from your unit test, which becomes not a unit test at all and more like an integration test - and how you would validate that the server process does the correct thing in response to client-side interactions becomes difficult unless you can observe the affect of the server-side code (interaction with database, etc.).

Comment: So you would suggest that this is actually an integration test? (I made the question more precise)

Comment: Yes - if you are trying to test the interaction of two very separate units of code - that is more of an integration test.  From what you described, I think some folks might test that by actually deploying in a sandbox both the client and server, interacting with the client, and then verifying the *results* of the server actions that should take place.  I think in this scenario a true unit test would be testing either the client or server independently of one another.  If my server recieves this signal (no real client need be running) - it should do x.  That would be a unit test.